# difference between binormal and bimodal?

Tags: sampling, bimodal

I am trying to simulate in R a normal distribution with two different means, and I wrote:

```
function(n,mean1,mean2, sd)
{ res=c()
  for (i in 1:n)
  { 
    switch(sample(1:2, 1),{x = rnorm(1, mean1, sd)}, {x = rnorm(1, mean2, sd)})
    res=c(res,x)
  }
  return(res)
}
```

The code serves my purpose, but I am wondering is this technically called bimodal distribution or binormal distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing the two concepts.

For any distribution the *mode* is the collection of points where the density function achieves it's maximum (assuming the distribution has a density function). For a normal distribution with mean *m* we have *m* as the only mode. In the distribution you coded you have two modes: mean1 and mean2 since you are mixing two normal distributions with differing means. This means that your distribution is *bimodal* because it has two modes.

On the other hand a *binormal* distribution is the two dimensional form of the [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). Your case is not a binormal distribution.

Comment: when one specifies the bimodal the formal definition is like this ~bimodal(1mean,2mean,sd)?

Comment: No. Being bimodal is a property of a distribution. Bimodal is not the name of a distribution.

Comment: so, how does one express it formaly? for normal I do ~N(mean,sd). How can I define formally the distribution express by that function?

Comment: I have never seen a notation for a particular mixture of distributions. The closest I can get to a notation is $F = 0.5 * N(mean1, sd^2) + 0.5 * N(mean2, sd^ 2)$, where $F$ is your cumulative distribution function and $N$ the same thing for a normal distribution.